# threeparttables in single table environment

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I have two `threeparttable` that I would like side by side in a single table environment. Previously I had a single `threeparttable` with a center column (of 5 columns) that had no borders, making it look like two tables within the same float. However, I'm sure this can be done, but I seem to be missing something since my tables are stacked on top of each other even though `tabular` is separated by `\qquad` and the `tablenotes` that apply to both tables are also aligned the same. MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Site} & \textbf{Size}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Cuoli} & 3.5 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Erlitou} & \textasciitilde{}5 ha \tnote{i}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Gaoya} & 57 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Huizui} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Ligou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule 
\textbf{Shaochai} & n/a \tnote{ii}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Tanxiaoguan} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Wangwan} & 2 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Xiaopangou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a) Longshan Period}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\qquad

\begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Site} & \textbf{Size}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Cuoli} & 3.5 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Erlitou} & 300 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Gaoya} & 80 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Huizui} & 25 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Ligou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Shaochai} & 100 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Tanxiaoguan} & 20 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Wangwan} & n/a \tnote{iii}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Xiaopangou} & 20 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b) Erlitou Period}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes} \scriptsize \item[i] The Erlitou site is occupied during the early Longshan period (see ), but the earlier occupation has been completely subsumed by the massive growth of the subsequent Erlitou period; the size given here is only an estimate. However, we do know that the site is abandoned during the late Longshan period, and is re-occupied by phase I of the Erlitou period. \item[ii] The Shaochai site is not present during the Longshan period, not appearing until phase I of the Erlitou period. \item[iii] The Wangwan site appears not to have much of a presence by the Erlitou period, though the Wangwan excavators do mention some Erlitou traits evident in pottery forms during the site's final occupation in the late Longshan (see "Wangwan Site" description, p.\pageref{WangwanSite}). \end{tablenotes}

\caption{Site sizes, by period}
\label{tab:Site-sizes-by-Period}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\textasciitilde{}` you may want to write either `$\sim$` or `$\approx`; the little raised tilde is a bit too easy to miss. Another thought: If you would rather not write `\tabularnewline` nearly two dozen times and prefer to write `\\ `, all you need to do is to modify the definition of the column header from `>{\centering}m{1.5cm}` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}`. Better still, if you provide the instruction `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` in the header, you can write `{rM{1.5cm}}` as the second argument of the inner `tabular` environments.

Comment: @Mico Great, thanks for the bonus formatting/coding tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose your two `tabular`s inside another `tabular` like

```
\begin{threeparttable}
 \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1cm}}c}
  \begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
    Content
  \end{tabular}
&
  \begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
    Content
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,array,showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1cm}}c}
\begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Site} & \textbf{Size}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Cuoli} & 3.5 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Erlitou} & \textasciitilde{}5 ha \tnote{i}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Gaoya} & 57 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Huizui} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Ligou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Shaochai} & n/a \tnote{ii}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Tanxiaoguan} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Wangwan} & 2 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Xiaopangou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a) Longshan Period}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{r>{\centering}m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Site} & \textbf{Size}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Cuoli} & 3.5 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Erlitou} & 300 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Gaoya} & 80 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Huizui} & 25 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Ligou} & 10 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Shaochai} & 100 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Tanxiaoguan} & 20 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Wangwan} & n/a \tnote{iii}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Xiaopangou} & 20 ha\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b) Erlitou Period}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes} \scriptsize \item[i] The Erlitou site is occupied during the early Longshan period (see ), but the earlier occupation has been completely subsumed by the massive growth of the subsequent Erlitou period; the size given here is only an estimate. However, we do know that the site is abandoned during the late Longshan period, and is re-occupied by phase I of the Erlitou period. \item[ii] The Shaochai site is not present during the Longshan period, not appearing until phase I of the Erlitou period. \item[iii] The Wangwan site appears not to have much of a presence by the Erlitou period, though the Wangwan excavators do mention some Erlitou traits evident in pottery forms during the site's final occupation in the late Longshan (see "Wangwan Site" description, p.\pageref{WangwanSite}). 
\end{tablenotes}
\caption{Site sizes, by period}
\label{tab:Site-sizes-by-Period}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, the ol' nested table trick. Excellent, thank you Harish! Didn't think I could do that in TeX, but once again I am wrong.

Comment: P.s. I just added a `\qquad` between the "framing" table and the `\begin{tablenotes}`--now they look grand!